# href to another element does not work in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, href

I created a project using the Polymer Starter Kit, with its app-router.

My my-app.html has the selectors for the views like so..

```
<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
      <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
      <my-view4 name="view4"></my-view4>
      <my-view5 name="view5"></my-view5>
      <my-view6 name="view6"></my-view6>
    </iron-pages>
```

I have a component my-view1.html, within which I have div with href tag

```
<div>God 1 <a href="#gotogod" class="link">Jump to example</a> </div>
```

elsewhere in the document I have

```
<p id="gotogod">
  God is great
</p>
```

While I dont get any errors, it doesnt jump to the paragraph when I click the link.  When I hover over the link, I do get

```
http://localhost:8080/view1#gotogod
```

But the page doesnt jump to that spot.

I have tried various combinations for the href without luck.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using the app-route element? (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route)

Comment: Yes. But I need to jump to an element

Comment: Ok, if your using app-route i'll put my answer right now about how to do it

Comment: Maybe it's dumb but... are you sure there's enough space in the page for the browser to scroll to the target element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Element:

```
<a on-click="scrollIntoView" section-id="gotogod">
```

Javascript Function:

```
scrollIntoView(e) {
   let sectionId = e.target.getAttribute('section-id');
   this.$[sectionId].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to be alert about the app-route, when you're going to change the route, you should change it by the app-route.

I do it (kind of) this way:

```
<app-location route="{{ route }}"></app-location>
<app-route route="{{ route }}"
           pattern="/:page"
           data="{{ routeData }}"
           tail="{{ subroute }}"></app-route>

<iron-selector attr-for-selected="route"
               selected="[[ page ]]"
               role="navigation">
    <a route="editor" href="/editor">Editor</a>
    <a route="analyze" href="/analyze">Analyze</a>
    <a route="community" href="/community">Community</a>
</iron-selector>

<iron-pages role="main"
            attr-for-selected="route"
            selected="[[ page ]]">
    <my-editor route="editor"></my-editor>
    <my-analyze route="analyze"></my-analyze>
    <my-community route="community"></my-community>
</iron-pages>

<script>
     Polymer({ 
         is:'my-element',
         properties: {
             page: {
                 type: String,
                 notify: true,
                 reflectToAttribute: true,
                 observer: "_pageChanged"
             }
         },

         observers: [
             "_routePageChanged(routeData.page)"
         ],

         listeners: {
             "requestChangeRoute": "_changeRoute"
         },

         attached: function(e) {
             // Lazyload the views as soon as the AppShell has been Painted
             this.importHref(
                 this.resolveUrl("my-editor.html"), null, null, true);
             this.importHref(
                 this.resolveUrl("my-analyze"), null, null, true);
             this.importHref(
                 this.resolveUrl("my-community"), null, null, true);

             // If the application is reloaded, redirect to /analyze
             if(this.page != "analyze"){
                 this.set("route.path", "/analyze");
             }
         },

         _changeRoute: function(e) {
             this.set("route.path", e.detail.requestRoute);
         },

         _routePageChanged: function(page) {
             this.page = page || "analyze";
         }
     })
</script>
```

On the main page, where the route is defined, you can use the href with route to navigate, but when you're inside some of your page elements, where there isn't the app-route defined, you should ask for you main page to change the route by the app-route using the function _changeRoute without href, this call is made like this:

```
this.fire("requestChangeRoute", {
    route: "/editor"
});
```

This way you have sure that the app-route is taking care of the navigation and that every page is going to work, and you can even set validations or parameters to be passed by this function.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I need to jump to a div with an id or an element (like paper card) in a page with an id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this answer is what you look for :
[Polymer scroll to a specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302820/polymer-scroll-to-a-specific-div)

You can do :

```
<a href="#gotogod" class="link" on-click="_goToGoScroll">
```

And in the code of the Polymer element :

```
_goToGoScrool() {
  this.$.gotogod.scrollIntoView();
}
```