# How do I change the route from inside a view in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

In a simple routing configuration in Polymer, like that obtained from the starter-kit:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer>
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
      <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
      <a name="view3" href="/view3">View Three</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
      <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
      <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
    </iron-pages>
  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

and a view with a button which if pressed should change the route, like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
      <paper-button raised on-tap="changeRoute">Change route</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',

      changeRoute() {
          // How to change route here?
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

how can I change the route programmatically, in the event handler above? I tried changing window.location without success (I'm inside Electron, not sure if it's part of the problem).

From the Polymer docs, about changing routes:

> Updating the route. The route object is read-write, so you can use
>   two-way data binding or this.set to update the route. Both the route
>   and routeData objects can be manipulated this way. For example:
>
> this.set('route.path', '/search/');
>
> Or:
>
> this.set('routeData.user', 'mary');

but this is correct (and works) if done inside the main component (the one that defines the routes), while it doesn't work if called inside a view. Another way to put this question maybe is: how can I access the main router object from an inner component?

Comment: I confirmed `this.set('route.path', ...)` works from `my-view1` in PSK, so the issue must be something particular to your code. Can you add some more context to the question?

Comment: I tried on a brand new Polymer project with `polymer init starter-kit`, adding just a paper-button in view1 with a callback and the `this.set("route.path", "/view2");` inside the callback. Pressing the button doesn't change the route. I don't know what to think, there is no more context outside what I've posted above :-/

Comment: Oh, I missed a change in my code: Pass `route` to the child with a two-way data binding so that the parent is notified of the child's changes to `route`. In `my-app.html`: `<my-view1 name="view1" route="{{route}}"></my-view1>`. Otherwise, you could use an event as suggested by @Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'view1' could fire a custom event that would trigger a route change in your app.

This would follow the observer pattern recommended in: [Thinking in Polymer (The Polymer Summit 2015)](https://youtu.be/ZDjiUmx51y8)

Note: the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323498/href-to-another-element-does-not-work-in-polymer) question may also help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks good to me, unfortunately I haven't time right now to look into it and implement this solution, I'll do as soon as I can.

Comment: Accepted because for my application is good to mantain some control over routing at higher level, while having lower level components generating messages.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few ways to do this, I may have gone overboard but I started to get into it so here goes...

Based on the answer you gave it looks like you just want to "go back". If that's the case you could just use

```
history.back();
```

Or if you want to move to a new path then a more robust, including more SEO friendly approach (I believe) is to use something like:

```
<a href="/newpath" tabindex="-1">
   <paper-button>Change Route</paper-button>
</a>
```

Or the answer by @Carlos works too, but the app-route "philosophy" seems to be more about allowing a decentralized routing approach & so passing an event up to let another component handle the route feels kind of like it's going against the grain. Although this is not necessarily the case since a component can be quite simple, maybe just a button, icon, etc, so you would probably want routing handled by a parent element. In this case though it looks like your component is a full view so I'd lean more towards it being a case where it might handle the routing itself.

I'd also say something similar to the above for @tony19's answer as well.

I think the biggest drawback of the approach in your own answer is that you're digging in the guts of another element so you've tightly coupled to it. That one is definitely not recommended.

Oh & one more way to change the route:

```
window.history.pushState({}, null, '/new_path');
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
```

This is given here - https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route#integrating-with-other-routing-code But this is really more for working with other routing code or special situations & would be pretty hacky in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and instructive answer. I'm building an Electron app so the browser history is not a good solution for me (although it would work, I think). I see there are several methods to change route and no one is the best for all situations. In my case I'll go with the event model proposed by @carlos-alberto-pereira-gomes

Answer (score 3):

Uhm. Turned out it was not so difficult:

```
document.querySelector("main-window").set('route.path', "/");
```

where main-window is the container component that defines the routes (first source file).

Does anyone have a better/more general approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it like by adding the routing-elements to the views as well:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/app/:view" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subRoute}}"></app-route>
<app-route route="{{subRoute}}" pattern="/:id" data="{{idData}}" active="{{onDetailPage}}"></app-route>
```

then you can change the route from within the element like this:

```
this.set("route.path", "/app/foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so with the *path* property of the app-location's element:

```js
changeRoute() {
  var $router = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("app-location");

  $router.path = "/view1";
}
```

Here the element's documentation [app-location](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/elements/app-location):

Setting the *path* property will fire up the path-changed event... This will begin the events' cascade to the *iron-pages* element and switch the view.